# How to hide a Floating button under textview while scrolling the texts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing an android application which has text view and floating action button. I want the button to show/hide when scrolling Textview. I have tried to use addOnScrollListner method but i think its only working on recyclerView not on Text View.
Can you tell how can i do it programmatically?
I put my textview inside Scrollview.

I appreciate your help!
Thank you

My Activity

```
package com.byc3.bman202.tafachlovetwo;

/**
 * Created by hp on 6/24/2017.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class abat1 extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout container;
    AnimationDrawable anim;
    TextView textView;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ab1);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice("3ACD2930EB5A1E83583AA8EA86BCAB53")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.fab2:
                        shareTextUrl();
                        break;
                    //case R.id.buttonShareImage:
                    //shareImage();
                    //break;

                }
            }

        };

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                shareTextUrl();
            }
        });
        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerab1);

        anim = (AnimationDrawable) container.getBackground();
        anim.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        anim.setExitFadeDuration(3000);
        findViewById(R.id.fab2).setOnClickListener(handler);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.addOnScrollListener(new TextView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(TextView textView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(teView, dx, dy);

                if (dy >0) {
                    // Scroll Down
                    if (floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                        floatingActionButton.hide();
                    }
                }
                else if (dy <0) {
                    // Scroll Up
                    if (!floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                        floatingActionButton.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void shareTextUrl() {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
        // what to do with it.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.ab1));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getString(R.string.shareit)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (anim != null && !anim.isRunning())
            anim.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (anim != null && anim.isRunning())
            anim.stop();
    }

}
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/containerab1"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_anim"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.byc3.bman202.tafachlovetwo.abat1">
    <ScrollView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/ab1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="12dp"
        android:gravity="start"/>
</ScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/color1"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                        if (scrollY > 0 && fab2.isShown()) {
                            fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (scrollY < 0) {
                            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        int mScrollY = mScrollView.getScrollY();
                        if (mScrollY > 0 && fab2.isShown()) {
                            fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (mScrollY < 0) {
                            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! That is close to my question answer. when i scroll up, button is hidden(that is what i need)  the problem is that when i scroll down the button remains gone. How can make it visible?

Comment: Its working fine in marshmallow, which device ur testing

Comment: Oh thank you so u much my friend, it's is now working now after i rebuild the project.

Comment: @Rashmi Bhandari unfortunately this not working for me, I tested it on two different devices first one android 8.0, second android lollipop, If there any solution for this issue please told me