# ScrollView with floating button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, floating-action-button

I have made an app where an activity contains two TextView, one ImageView and FloatingActionButton. I want to make the layout like this.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


 <!--    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" /> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blogContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtubeThumbnailImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icons8_share_480"
            app:fabSize="auto"

            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and I use the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825413/4205927) to make it hide when scroll down on all android api's.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    if (scrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (scrollY < 0) {
                        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    int mScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                    if (mScrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (mScrollY < 0) {
                        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This works on android 6.0. But higher than 6.0, the floating button appears on the corner top right of activity. Here is the pic below.

[image: the current]

I tried many property options like-  `android:layout_gravity=""` and put the FloatingButton directly on main LinearLayout or FrameLayout. Still these Layouts did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CoordinatorLayout, you should try setting the FloatingActionButtons anchor to reference the LinearLayout and the use `layout_anchorGravity` to position the FAB.

Example code for your FAB:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearLayoutID"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8_share_480"
        />
```

Remember to set an ID for you LinearLayout. I  used `@id/linearLayoutID` as a placeholder.

Comment: I see this error Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\Courses\Java\Android Projects\DummyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_details.xml:16: error: attribute android:layout_anchor not found.
D:\Courses\Java\Android Projects\DummyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_details.xml:16: error: attribute android:layout_anchorGravity not found.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, must have missed that. I hope this solution works for you.